# How did character ž got encoded to C3 85 C2 BE

Tags: unicode, encoding

We had a legacy PHP 5 application that was storing data in mysql database. Now, only the database remains and I need to get the data out of this database.

I know that ž (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+017E) is stored in the database as C3 85 C2 BE

ü (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00FC) is stored ad C3 83 C2 BC

Could someone help me figure out what type of conversion/encoding could result in such representation? Perhaps some kind of double-encoding was taking place?

Thank you so much for any ideas!

Comment: This is a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. The letter `ž` is represented in _UTF-8_ by byte sequence `0xC5`,`0xBE`  (a Python example: `'ž'.encode( 'utf-8')` returns `b'\xc5\xbe'`). Your byte sequence comes from mojibake as follows: `'ž'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1').encode( 'utf-8')` returns `b'\xc3\x85\xc2\xbe'`…

Comment: Thank you, JosefZ! Any idea how to reverse the encoding in PHP?

Comment: Try https://kunststube.net/encoding/